# cookstyle: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra

I'm learning Chef via Udemy, and one of the topics is to test cookbook syntax with cookstyle. I wrote a very simple cookbook and tried to test it with cookstyle:

```
path/to/Chef# cat test-cookbook.rb

user "spencer" do
  shell '/bin/bash'
  uid '9999'
end

path/to/Chef# cookstyle test-cookbook.rb
cookstyle: command not found
```

The tutorial is using ChefDK, which I've found is outdated. I used `apt install chef` as root, which I assume is downloading the workstation, and I tried running cookstyle as root also. Is cookstyle outdated, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chef` package contains only some binaries and Chef libraries for the client. Quoting from output of  `apt info chef` command:

> This package provides the chef-client, chef-solo, and knife binaries as well
> as the Chef library.

This does not contain the Chef workstation package. Chef workstation can be downloaded from: https://www.chef.io/downloads/tools/workstation.

The `cookstyle` command will be available when you install workstation.

Comment: This is the direction I'm heading. I'm using an environment different from the one I started learning on, and I don't think I installed everything I needed on the new one. I'll update when everything is confirmed as installed. Thanks!

Comment: It turned out that my installs for server and workstation got tangled up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to know that it was useful for you.